# How can I completely terminate the running go func() when ctx times out?

Tags: go

When I want ctx timeout, what should I do to completely terminate the method that is executing longRunningCalculation()?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func longRunningCalculation(timeCost int) chan string {
    result := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * (time.Duration(timeCost)))
        log.Println("Still doing other things...") //Even if it times out, this goroutine is still doing other tasks.
        result <- "Done"
        log.Println(timeCost)
    }()
    return result
}
func jobWithTimeout() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Println(ctx.Err())
        return
    case result := <-longRunningCalculation(3):
        log.Println(result)
    }
}

func main() {
    jobWithTimeout()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}
```

What did you expect to see?
2019/09/25 11:00:16 context deadline exceeded

What did you see instead?
2019/09/25 11:00:16 context deadline exceeded
2019/09/25 11:00:17 Still doing other things...

Comment: You cannot make someone else's code stop. You can make *your* code stop, by having your code ask (at appropriate points) "should I stop now?"  If it gets an answer telling it to stop now, it can stop. If it calls someone else's routine that takes too long, there's nothing you can really do about that.

Comment: It’s true that the logic is complicated.

Comment: There's no magic in Go. If you want your goroutine to stop, you need to make it stop. It doesn't just magically infer that there's some related context floating around somewhere, and act on it.

Answer (score 2):

To stop the goroutine started by `longRunningCalculation` when the caller's context times out, you need to pass `ctx` into `longRunningCalculation` and explicitly handle the context timing out, the same way you do in `jobWithTimeout`

Doing things that way also means instead of calling `time.Sleep`, that `time.Tick` will be a better choice, so both timers are running at the same time. Like so:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func longRunningCalculation(ctx context.Context, timeCost int) chan string {
    result := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        calcDone := time.Tick(time.Second * time.Duration(timeCost))
        log.Printf("entering select (longRunningCalculation)")
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            result <- "Caller timed out"
            return
        case <-calcDone:
            log.Println("Still doing other things...") //Even if it times out, this goroutine is still doing other tasks.
            result <- "Done"
        }
        log.Println(timeCost)
    }()
    return result
}

func jobWithTimeout() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    result := longRunningCalculation(ctx, 3)
    log.Printf("entering select (jobWithTimeout)")
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Println(ctx.Err())
        return
    case res := <-result:
        log.Println(res)
    }
}

func main() {
    jobWithTimeout()
}
```

Comment: `case <-calcDone:`This is not true, it is waiting for 3 seconds to receive the signal to execute, as if there is really no way to terminate the logic being executed.

Comment: when using context in a function it should always be the first argument as defined in the go standard

Comment: In order to be able to interrupt `longRunningCalculation`, you'll have to break up the work it does, and check `<-ctx.Done()` inbetween those smaller chunks of work. As others have said, there isn't a magic way to stop a goroutine once it's started, you have to ask the caller if it's time to stop via `<-ctx.Done()`.